# Taxonomy URL Inside View

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I've created a View that displays all of my 'Product Category' taxonomies. I'd also like to get the path alias for each taxonomy listed. Usually to do this, I'll add a hidden 'Path' field, so I have access to it in my Twig template.

There doesn't seem to be that 'Path' field though, the closest I can find is 'Link to Taxonomy term' field. This isn't what I'm after though as this field seems to be preformatted, when all I want is an absolute URL. I've tried playing around with the rewrite rules of this field, but none of the changes seem to take affect.

Is there a way for me to convert the Term ID I have access to into my system path or path alias of my taxonomy pages? Is there a different way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add the field `Taxonomy term: Term ID` to your list. On the settings of this field you have options for `Rewrite results` check the box `Output this field as a custom link` on the path option you can write it `taxonomy/term/{{ tid }}` and below to can check the box `Use absolute path` if you want too.

This will automatically convert the link into alias if it exists.